# View returns 404 when including a queryset despite the object being valid

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using the following URL pattern to pass a primary key for a model to the view class detailed below it. The primary key of the related model, "Host", is either a valid IP address or FQDN.

URL Pattern:

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
ValidHostnameRegex = "(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])"

url(r"^host/(?P<pk>({}|{}))/$".format(ValidIpAddressRegex, ValidHostnameRegex),
    views.HostView.as_view(),
    name="host")
```

View class:

```
class HostView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Host
    template_name = 'report_viewer/host.html'
    context_object_name = 'related_findings'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return all related findings"""
        host = get_object_or_404(Host, name=self.kwargs["pk"])
        return host.get_findings()  # A function on the model to return related records from another model
```

Relevant template:

```
<ul>
    {% for finding in related_findings %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'report_viewer:finding' finding.plugin_id %}"><strong>{{ finding.plugin_id }}</strong> {{ finding.plugin_name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No findings!</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Host model:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    os_general = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Generic OS Identifier")
    os_specific = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Reported OS Name")
    ssh_fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="SSH Fingerprint")
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True, verbose_name="MAC Address")
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="IP Address")
    fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Fully Qualified Domain Name")
    netbios_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="NetBIOS Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_findings(self):
        findings = Finding.objects.filter(targets=self)
        return findings

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

The result of a valid URL is "No finding found matching the query", raised by views.HostView. The view below works successfully, invoking the {% empty %} condition, which suggests that I'm either constructing the get_object_or_404 request incorrectly, or perhaps the "pk" variable is being mangled and is not a valid key.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on a solution. Or indeed an alternative method to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Please show your Host model, as well as the "valid URL" you are going to.

Comment: Added the Host model to the OP. The valid URL is on a local development deployment, so it's 127.0.0.1/host/192.168.0.1, with the IP address being the relevant PK ("name") for the Host model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was a great deal simpler than expected. I was attempting to use the `get_queryset` function with the generic DetailView, when it's meant to be used with ListView.

I rewrote the model to use the `get_context_data` function instead.

```
class HostView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Host
    template_name = 'report_viewer/host.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Return all related findings"""
        context = super(HostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['host'] = get_object_or_404(Host, name=self.kwargs["pk"])
        context['findings'] = context['host'].get_findings()
        return context
```

Which then allows me to access the relevant Host model and all its related Finding models in the template.